# How do you protect against XSRF in Grails?

Tags: grails, csrf

How does one protect against XSRF attacks in Grails. I see that forms support the notion of useToken which (I think should suffice). However, remoteForm or other AJAX related request don't support this feature.

Also, is there a way to invert the functionality of useToken so that it is always used rather than enabled on a case by case basis?

Comment: I know that [checking HTTP Referer header is not enough](http://www.secureworks.com/research/blog/research/21009/), but it's a better-than-nothing start, especially if you don't allow empty referers.  And this is rather easy to add as a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking at the source code of the [*<g:form>*](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/form.html) tag. It uses a [*SynchronizerToken*](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/SynchronizerToken.html) to create a token and store it in the session. Based on the resolution of [this issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/6973) it should be possible to use the same token for all forms on the same page. I did not try this, but theoretically you would just need to manually create a hidden field on the form and generate the token in that field.

Answer (score 0):

We have inject a hidden value to the request object in a before filter and encrypt the value with a specific key. We then inject that request.token value to every form on the site and when we receive a POST we have a before filter to verify that that hidden field is present and its value can be decoded by that same secret key.

If that hidden value is not present or if it is stale -- we use a timestamp as payload -- we give the client an error status.

This is an alternative way to what was described above and we use this, because we do not use sessions on our sites to make it easier to load balance.